# LNK1104 when using full rebuild, but incremental builds work visual studio 2012 express

Tags: c++, build, visual-studio-2012

I have a solution with 3 projects, project1, project2 and project3 in visual studio 2012 (express). 2 depends on 1 and 3 depends on 1 and 2. All are multi-threaded dlls. I builld project 1 fine and it creates project1.lib. project2 includes project1.lib and also builds fine. However, if I rebuild project2 it gives LNK1104 that it cannot find project1.lib

This problem occurs if I build for x64, but does not occur for Win32. Include & build directories are all the same.

I am rather puzzled? Any ideas?

Comment: Any prebuild or post build events or batch files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a problem where I used the same intermediary directory for project1, project2, and project3. This is not advisable. After giving all their own intermediary directory the problem went away.